# TypeScript: How to get inheritance type of class

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I'm writing a compiler, and different "Statement" types have different classes. A Block Statement has a BlockStatement class, an If Statement has an IfStatement class, etc.

I need to be able to tell what type of object I'm working with at runtime, eg

```
class BlockStatement extends Statement {
    constructor(...children: Statement[]) {
        super()

        this.rep.assemble(
            new BlockLabel(),
            children.map(child => Statement.extractRep(child))
        )
    }

    private addToBlock(pos: number, s: Statement): void {
        this.rep.addChild(pos, Statement.extractRep(s))
    }
}

function prettyPrint(s: Statement) {
    switch () {
        case 'BlockStatement': {
        }

    }
}
```

How can I tell what type of Statement I am working with? And even if I can tell, will it not matter since it may slice any inherited functionality since the parameter is a statement?

Comment: Slicing doesn't happen in JavaScript. You can use `instanceof` to test. Personally, I wouldn't use classes for this sort of thing, just an object like `{kind: 'BlockStatement', children: [], ...etc}` and then `switch (statement.kind) {...}` but it's your call.

Comment: Thanks. s.constructor.name seemed to work, and then i just casted it as whatever it is so intellisense works.

Comment: That's very ugly though, and if you find yourself needing to use things like generics, classes will leave you high and dry. Take a look at how the TypeScript compiler itself is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###object###.constructor.name does the trick, however, ive heard minifying may cause issues with this. Then cast itself as whatever it is so intellisense works

Comment: You don't want to use the name, you use a reference comparison like `switch (statement.constructor) { case BlockStatement: }`